# Como pegar url atual com o PHP

Tags: php

Tenho esse link abaixo.

```
http://example.com/Novo/adm/categoria/1-Nome_Categoria

http://example.com/Novo/adm.php?categoria=1
```

Porém vou precisar comparar URL atual, para fazer um esquema de ativação de menus.

Abaixo o código que exibo esse resultado acima.

```
<?php 
    $URL_ATUAL= "http://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]";
    echo $URL_ATUAL;
?>
```

Por precisar fazer essa comparação eu só preciso pegar a URL abaixo.

```
adm/categoria/1-Nome_Categoria
```

Eu tentei usar o explode mas não retornou a URL correta.

Comment: Não seria apenas o valor de `$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]`?

Comment: Está apenas me retornando. 

`Novo/adm/categoria/1-Nome_Categoria`

Queria que me retornasse apenas **adm** pra frente.

Comment: Tem que cortar a URI

Comment: Todas as URL's que for pegar tem adm  na frente  ? ou sempre quer cortar o primeiro caminho ?

Comment: URI está retornando o caminho correto, porém, gostaria de remover da string esse **Novo**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Como dito nos comentários, o conteúdo da variável global `$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]` é da forma:

```
Novo/adm/categoria/1-Nome_Categoria
```

Foi expresso também nos comentários que o conteúdo de interesse é apenas a parte de `adm` em diante, então basta tratar este valor, removendo aquilo que não é de interesse. Isso pode ser feito de várias formas.

Se o nome do diretório não for alterado com o tempo, apenas remover o conteúdo da string já é suficiente:

```
$url = str_replace("Novo/", "", $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]);
```

Desta forma, `$url` seria `adm/categoria/1-Nome_Categoria`, como desejado.

Se o nome do diretório for passível de alterações com o tempo, mas sempre houver um diretório, você pode apenas remover o primeiro trecho da string até a primeira ocorrência de `/`:

```
$url = substr($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"], strpos($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"], '/')+1);
```

O resultado será o mesmo, independente de qual é o nome do diretório, desde que exista um.

Se existir a possibilidade de houver mais de um diretório, mas que a URL sempre se iniciará com `adm`, você pode buscar por este trecho na sua URL, desta forma:

```
$url = substr($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"], strpos($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"], 'adm'));
```

O resultado também seria o mesmo, independente da quantidade e nome dos diretórios presentes na URL.

Comment: Excelente tutorial amigo, acrescentei uma `/` no começo e realmente funcionou do jeito que era pra funcionar.


`$url = str_replace("/Novo/", "", $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]);`

Comment: Olha eu gostaria de saber o seguinte:

`http://example.com/Novo/adm/categoria/1-Nome_Categoria`

`http://example.com/Novo/adm.php?categoria=1-Nome_Categoria`

Gostaria de saber se consigo verificar se esse categoria vier (Numérico) e se consigo exibir tipo assim.

`http://example.com/Novo/adm/categoria/1-Nome_Categoria`

`http://example.com/Novo/adm.php?categoria=1`

Comment: Exibir onde? Se esta pergunta for muito diferente das atual, talvez seja interessante criar uma nova para discutirmos isso.

Answer (score 2):

pode usar

```
<?php
echo $_SERVER['SCRIPT_URI'];
?>
```

ou a forma curta

```
<?=$_SERVER['SCRIPT_URI']?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Eu tenho uma classe bem legal pra essa tarefa, fique a vontade para utilizá-la, opinar, estudar, etc...

Esta seria a forma de utilização da mesma:

```
<?php $uri = URI::base(); echo $uri; ?>
```

ou somente...

```
<?php echo URI::base(); ?>
```

https://github.com/webrafael/Projetos/tree/master/pegar-url-principal-php

Abaixo a estrutura da classe

```
<?php
class URI {

/**
 * $protocolo
 * @var string | $protocolo
 * @access private
 */
static private $protocolo;
/**
 * $host
 * @var string | $host
 * @access private
 */
static private $host;
/**
 * $scriptName
 * @var string | $scriptName
 * @access private
 */
static private $scriptName;
/**
 * $finalBase
 * @var string | $finalBase
 * @access private
 */
static private $finalBase;

/**
 * protected function Protocolo()
 * ----------------------------------------------
 *            Obtém o protocolo da url
 * ----------------------------------------------
 * @return string | Ex: http://... - https://...
 * @access protected
 */
protected function Protocolo()
{
    /**
     * Faz a verificação se for
     * diferente de https
     */
    if(strpos(strtolower($_SERVER['SERVER_PROTOCOL']),'https') === false)
    {
        self::$protocolo = 'http://'; //Atribui o valor http
    }
    else
    {
        self::$protocolo = 'https://'; //Atribui o valor https
    }
    /**
     * Retorna o protocolo em formato string
     * @var string
     */
    return self::$protocolo;
}
/**
 * protected function Host()
 * ----------------------------------------------
 *            Obtém o host principal
 * ----------------------------------------------
 * @return string | Ex: www.example.com.br
 * @access protected
 */
protected function Host()
{
    self::$host = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']; //Atribui o valor www.example.com.br
    /**
     * Retorna o host em formato string
     * @var string
     */
    return self::$host;
}
/**
 * protected function scriptName()
 * ----------------------------------------------
 * Obtém o script name do host após a primeira barra
 * ----------------------------------------------
 * @return string | Ex: .../dir/index.php
 * @access protected
 */
protected function scriptName()
{
    /**
     * $scr
     * Atribui o valor do SCRIPT_NAME em uma
     * variável $scr e utiliza-se a função dirname()
     * para remover qualquer nome de arquivo .html, .php, etc...
     * @var string
     */
    $scr = dirname($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']);
    /**
     * Faz a contagem de barras que contém a url principal
     * o objetivo aqui é pegar o nível de pasta onde hospeda-se o diretório
     * caso ele exista.
     */
    if(!empty($scr) || substr_count($scr, '/') > 1)
    {
        self::$scriptName = $scr . '/'; //atribui o valor do diretório com uma "/" na sequência
    }
    else
    {
        self::$scriptName = ''; //atribui um valor vazio
    }
    /**
     * Retorna o scriptName em formato string
     * @var string
     */
    return self::$scriptName;
}
/**
 * public function base()
 * ----------------------------------------------
 *          Monta a url base e retorna
 * ----------------------------------------------
 * @return [type] [description]
 * @access public
 */
public function base()
{
    //Concatena os valores
    self::$finalBase = self::Protocolo() . self::Host() . self::scriptName();
    /**
     * Retorna toda a url construida em formato string
     * @var string
     */
    return self::$finalBase;
}
}
?>
```

Comment: Tudo bem, coloquei a resposta mais completa o possível para ser mais objetivo.